# Is the salutation remover working properly?

Tags: support, signatures

I was wondering whether the [automagically salutation remover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) (already) working properly or not? It seems like a very convenient piece of code, but I still notice a lot of salutations (which should be caught by the code as far as I understand).

Some recent examples with salutations:

- [File exchange API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972882/file-exchange-api)
- [PHP Syntax needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972965/php-syntax-needed)
- [No response for my WCF web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973054/no-response-for-my-wcf-web-service)

and there are many more.

Comment: I edited the posts to remove the "Hi's" so you'll need to check the revision histories.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the first one choked maybe because of the bold.  The others, no punctuation.  Seems reasonable why it didn't catch it.

Comment: @Jeff Mercando: Looks like you are right, I only see salutations without punctuation (eg [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974769/shell-cut-command-to-remove-characters)). I suppose it is too risky to filter out those ones as well with the salutation remover?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We generally only remove salutations when *they are on a line by themselves*. These 3 all begin like

> Hi I foo bar baz...
>
> Hello guys I foo bar baz..
>
> Hi my question foo bar baz..

It's much riskier to remove a salutation without being able to use EOL as a definitive end marker, so we don't try...